# JupyterLab/debugger - Adjust variable list

Tags: jupyter-lab

I started working with the debugger in JupyterLab. In general, it is working, but the variable list is quite long and full os some kind of system variables. Looking at the official tutorials, there are only the "python variables" visible.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance!

**[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrWds.png)**

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the `Settings` menu → `Advanced Settings Editor` → `Debugger` and then adjust the `variableFilters` setting in the User Preferences (right panel) to you liking:

[image: debugger settings]

Remember to press save.

Edit: as some users appear to come here for a copy-paste answer (which I never recommend - do not paste code you do not understand!), here is a little snippet that will eliminate a lot of noise from IPython history:

```
{
    "variableFilters": {
        "xpython": [
            "_",
            "quit",
            "exit",
            "debugpy",
            "get_ipython",
            "_i",
            "_ii",
            "_iii",
            "_ih",
            "_oh",
            "_dh",
            "Out",
            "In",
            "_i1",
            "_i2",
            "_i3",
            "_i4",
            "_i5",
            "_i6",
            "_i7",
            "_i8",
            "_i9",
            "_i10",
            "_i11",
            "_i12",
            "_i13",
            "_i14",
            "_i15",
            "_i16",
            "_i17",
            "_i18",
            "_i19",
            "_i20",
        ]
    }
}
```