# jupyterlab debugging mode contains many variables, what are they?

Tags: variables, debugging, ipython, jupyter-lab, xeus-python

I have last version of jupyterlab Version 3.0.14
in debugging mode many variables not needed exists in the right box
what are they?
I want to delete them except `i`, `j` and `result`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the `variableFilters` setting of the debugger to hide variable that you are not interested in; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66318470/6646912) for more details.

The debugger simply shows all variables that are available at runtime in the kernel; the Python kernels (IPython and Xeus Python) come with a feature of remembering your input and output for each executed cell; it is immensely useful if you execute a cell with compute-intensive task but forget to assign the result onto a variable, for example instead of:

```
result = do_long_calculation()
```

you do:

```
do_long_calculation()
```

in the latter case you can use the IPython underscore `_` variable which caches the last execution result to recover the output:

```
result = _
```

If you already overwritten the most recent output, it the previous one goes to `__` and so on. Learn more about this in the [output caching system documentation](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system).
Similarly `_i`, `_ii`, etc. variables cache most recent input of cells so you can check **what** has been executed. See more in [input caching system documentation](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html#input-caching-system). There are also `In` and `Out` variables which store entire execution history for your reference.

Fur the future convenience I raised the idea of allowing regular expressions to hide all variables matching a pattern [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9903#issuecomment-834061227).

Comment: what is the difference between _45, _ih, ___i5,  can I reduce these variables more than that?  and how to show complete matrix or array in debugger

Comment: This is described in the documentation to which I linked in the answe: *In, _ih : a list of all inputs; _ih[n] is the input from line n. If you overwrite In with a variable of your own, you can remake the assignment to the internal list with a simple In=_ih.*. What do you mean by *reduce*? Have you looked at the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66293084/jupyterlab-debugger-adjust-variable-list/66318470#66318470)?

Comment: As for rendering of matrices/arrays, it is currently scheduled for JupyterLab 4.0, see [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9867).

Comment: do you mean it is not released yet?! when jupyterlab 4.0 is available?

Comment: I mean that while matrices/arrays display in a textual form already, the fancy rendering in tabular form was not implemented yet and is scheduled for JupyterLab 4.0 which is planned for the end 2021/beginning of 2022 (you can subscribe for updates [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9647)). There is no need to shout at me - you are using an open source project **for free** that respects your privacy and is developed in a sustainable manner (meaning it won't get abandoned), with volunteer contributors like me who do not get paid for helping you but do it in their free time.

Comment: I am sorry Sir I didn't shout, I'm just asking because I'm new in python and jupyterlab , I am very grateful for your help, thanks alot for your time and help