# I need to understand in jupyterlab debugger in details

Tags: debugging, jupyter-lab

I use jupyterlab for debugging , it gives alot of variables, and system variables that I can't understand which make debugging so hard for me

I changed the user prefernces as in figure but it is still hard for me to understand arrays and matrix

what is the meaning of variables __22 to _45 , _ih, _i5

[image: jupyterlab]

Comment: I already answered your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67398955/6646912

Comment: Please do not answer two very similar questions in a short span of time. If you have questions about the answers you received, please comment on them. If the answers helped please upvote them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jupyterlab debugging mode contains many variables, what are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67395153/jupyterlab-debugging-mode-contains-many-variables-what-are-they)

Comment: (You see the comment above because I now voted to mark this question as a duplicate of your earlier one; this is meant to allow others to find the answer more easily, especially if this version of the question gets indexed by search engines better)